# Rearrange react components on resize

Tags: reactjs

Is this even possible(title)? I need it, because in css @media rule needs to change some element's css. CSS part works. Problem occurs because it needed to be followed by rearranging react components. I have these conditions whom(both of them), pass. It should be, when window resizes, css get applied and after getting window width, components get rearranged following css change.
I have this in constructor:

```
this.myInput = React.createRef();
```

and this:

```
componentDidMount () {
        this.setState({
            myWidth: this.state.myWidth=this.myInput.current.offsetWidth
        });
    }
```

and this in Render():

```
render(){

    const btnText = this.state.erase ? "Populate" : "Erase" ;
    const handleClick = e => this.fullScreen(e.target.id);

    const EditorHead1 = <EditorHead id={"item1"} style={this.state.stilEditor} className={this.state.headEdKlasa} onClick={handleClick} title={this.state.attr}/>;
    const PreviewHead1 = <PreviewHead id={"item2"} style={this.state.stilPreview} className={this.state.headViewKlasa} onClick={handleClick} title={this.state.attr}/>;
    const BtnEraser1 = <BtnEraser id={"eraser"} onClick={this.eraseFields} type={"button"} className={"btn btn-danger btn-lg"} title={"Erase & populate both fields"} value={btnText}/>;
    const Editor1 = <Editor id={"editor"} onChange={this.handleChange} className={this.state.editorKlasa} value={this.state.markdown} placeholder={"Enter ... some kind a text!? ..."} title={"This is rather obvious isnt it? Its editor window Sherlock :D"}/>;
    const Preview1 = <Preview id={"preview"} className={this.state.previewKlasa} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: marked(this.state.markdown, { renderer: renderer })}} title={"Its a preview window, Sherlock ;)"}/>;
    const Arrow1 = <Arrow id={"arrow"}/>;

    if(this.state.myWidth<=768){
        alert("Alternative");
        alert(this.state.myWidth);
        return (

            <div id="inner2" ref={this.myInput} className="grid-container animated zoomIn" style={{height: this.state.inner2H}} onDoubleClick={this.inner2Height}>

                {EditorHead1}
                {Editor1}
                {PreviewHead1}
                {Preview1}
                {BtnEraser1}
                {Arrow1}

            </div>

        );
    }
    if(this.state.myWidth>768){
        alert("Normal");
        alert(this.state.myWidth);
        return (

            <div id="inner2" ref={this.myInput} className="grid-container animated zoomIn" style={{height: this.state.inner2H}} onDoubleClick={this.inner2Height}>

                {EditorHead1}
                {PreviewHead1}
                {BtnEraser1}
                {Editor1}
                {Preview1}
                {Arrow1}

            </div>

        );
    }
    }
```

Currently rearranging only works if you, after resize, refresh browser or “run” again codepen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`resize` event should be listened in order to keep track of element width changes. It's preferable to debounce event handlers for events that can be fired often, which `resize` is:

```
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';

...

myInput = React.createRef();

setMyWidth = () => {
    this.setState({
      myWidth: this.myInput.current.offsetWidth
  });
}

onResize = debounce(this.setMyWidth, 100);

componentDidMount() {
  this.setMyWidth();
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize);

}

componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', this.onResize);
}
```

Depending on what element `offsetWidth` is, element reference may be redundant, `document.body.clientWidth` can be tracked instead.

Also, `this.state.myWidth=...` is a mistake, `this.state` shouldn't be changed directly outside component constructor.

Comment: Thnaks dude. After reading your solution and couple articles, it all clicked.